# In a html table cell, how can I force images to be the bottom left and the bottom right that have different heights?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with text  and images.  I now want to add a few images and have them aligned to the bottom of the cell.  What is the correct CSS to force an image to be aligned to the bottom left of a cell?

Here is the relevant CSS:

```
 .bottomRight {
     bottom: 0;
     float: right;
  }

.bottomLeft {
    bottom: 0;
    float: left;
  }
```

Here is my html:

```
   <td width="240">

    <span style="float:right;margin-left: 1px; margin-bottom: 1px;">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;<b></b>
    </span>
    Info
    <br/><br/>

     <img src="/Content/shortImage.png" class="bottomLeft">
     <img class="bottomRight" height="35" width="35" title="Name" src="/Content/tallImage.jpg" >
 </td>
```

The image tallImage.jpg does work and shows up at the bottom right but the shortImage.png which is smaller in height doesn't go all the way to the bottom of the table cell.

Any suggestions on how i get the shortImage and largeImage to both align to bottom of a table cell?

Comment: Can you post the HTML?

Comment: without your html, noway to give you the good advise, your CSS will show what you try and maybe what gos wrong too

Comment: vertical-align: bottom doesn't work?

Comment: You wrote `vertical-align: bottom;` wrong. No need for `bottom: 0;`

Comment: As a side note, consider using CSS alone for formatting the layout of your page rather than using tables (unless you are displaying tabular data).

Comment: @j08691 - i have updated the question with my css and html

Comment: @Ty Bailey - that was a typo. i fixed the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `vertical-align:bottom;`

**If you differentiate your selected elements, why not use a class?**

#### http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/x3vc7/2/

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Hello world</td>
        <td class="image">
            <img src="http://www.itworldcanada.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Windows-XP-migration-FEature-Image-42x42.jpg" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
td {
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
.image {
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

---

## EDIT:

I said let us continue this discussion in `chat`. If your idea is to display `non-tabuler-data`. [Read here about tabular data](http://webdesign.about.com/od/tables/a/aa122605.htm).

### You Should Not Use a Table If:

The main purpose of the table is to position the contents on the page in some way. For example, to add spacing around an image, to place "bullet" icons on a list, or to force a block of text to act like a pull quote.

Comment: i don't want the entire TD to align to bottom, just the image

Comment: K, let me `remap` the answer.

Comment: Updated with your question.

Comment: You are still putting a class at the TD level.  I DON"T want the whole TD to be vertically aligned at the bottom.  JUST the image

Comment: no you didn't, you have a TD with a class name called "image" and you are setting that class name to be vertical-align:bottom.  That is setting the property on the TD (not just the image).  Think about if there was some text in that TD. would that be vertically aligned top or bottom?

Comment: `I feel that is a problem with your question, because I answered it` However, more than happy to help. One moment please. I understand what you want.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45504/discussion-between-nicholas-hazel-and-leora)

Comment: Me helping you has hurt my record. Please ask a `further defined` question if you want a relevant answer. `Tables are not the way to display this structure.` If my answer helped, please accept it with the `green checkbox` next to the voting arrows.

Comment: if you add some text to your td "image", you will see that its not isolating the image and it vertically aligns everything in the table cell

Comment: I do have tabular data. This is just what is inside each cell.  I updated the question to make it simpler to isolate the issue and more explicit.  Hopefully that helps explain the issue